# Indexing and Partitioning: Improving SqlServer 2008 R2 query performance

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance, partitioning

I have a database in 'SQL Server 2008 R2' that its size is about 5 TB and it grows in size continuously.
I have some problem with running a simple query on tbl1 with hundreds of million rows:

```
select x1,x2,x3
from tbl1
where date > '2017-04-03 00:00:00.000' and date < '2017-04-04 00:00:00.000'
      and mid = 300
```

this query takes about 20 seconds.
I have two non-clustered indexes on `date` and `mid` columns and this query takes advantage of them.

What is the best idea for improving performance of `select` and `insert` in this table? (such as automatic partitioning)

I'm using `Entity Framework`, so I don't want to change the name of the table or partitioning it into some different names.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: which *edition* of sql-server-2008-r2 are you using?

Comment: @MikeNakis : Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit)

Comment: oh, the flagship.  You are in luck, because this edition does everything with regards to partitioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your question is stated it leads me to believe that you are under the impression that partitioning is something that you have to do manually, i.e. splitting a table into multiple tables each having a different name.

That's not the case.

With ms-sql-server, all you need to do in order to partition your tables and indexes is to issue the `CREATE PARTITION` commands.  So, go ahead and look them up:

[CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-function-transact-sql)

[CREATE PARTITION SCHEME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-scheme-transact-sql)

So, in your case I would presume that you would partition on the `date` column, probably putting each year on a different partition, or possibly even each month on a different partition.

However, be aware that your question might be a case of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The difficulty you are having seems to be performance related.  You appear to have arrived at the conclusion that what you need to do in order to solve your problem is partitioning, so you are posting a question about partitioning.  I am answering your question, but it may well be the case that your problem is not partitioning.  It could be a large number of other things, for example locking: if your table is so huge and it is continuously growing, then what is probably happening is that rows are being continuously added to it, so it could be that your `SELECT`s are fighting against your `INSERT`s for access to the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About the X-Y problem that you said: I have a service that `insert`s the data into the DB. When I stop the service, the problem still exists.

Comment: When I check the `execution plan` in the `Management Studio`, everything is looking good (about using the indexes and...). But in reality executing the query isn't the way as I expected, it takes too much time.

Comment: Eventually, I partitioned two of the tables that were very large into some pieces based on the 'date' and the problem was completely solved.

Comment: Glad to hear that, @pedram !